# How to prevent requestAnimationFrame from redrawing canvas more then one time after clicking the button?

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas, requestanimationframe, cancelanimationframe

I am drawing canvas sin and adding movement to it

```
export class CanvasComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('canvas', { static: true })
  canvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  winddrawvalue = 0;
  windvalue = 0;

  constructor() { }

  @Input() set speeddata(speed: number){
    this.windvalue = speed;
    this.drawWind();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
  }

  drawWind() {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.drawWind.bind(this));
    const canvas = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    this.ctx.beginPath();

    this.ctx.moveTo(-10, canvas.height / 2 - 12);
    for (let i = 0; i < canvas.width; i++) {
      this.ctx.lineTo(i, canvas.height / 2 - 12 + Math.sin(i * 0.04 + this.winddrawvalue) * 15);
    }

    this.ctx.moveTo(-10, canvas.height / 2);
    for (let i = 0; i < canvas.width; i++) {
      this.ctx.lineTo(i, canvas.height / 2 + Math.sin(i * 0.04 + this.winddrawvalue) * 15);
    }

    this.ctx.moveTo(-10, canvas.height / 2 + 12);
    for (let i = 0; i < canvas.width; i++) {
      this.ctx.lineTo(i, canvas.height / 2 + 12 + Math.sin(i * 0.04 + this.winddrawvalue) * 15);
    }

    this.ctx.stroke();
    this.winddrawvalue += this.windvalue;
  }

}
```

And everytime i am pressing button to draw it again canvas is redrawing it but it moves 2 times faster then before.
I tried to do

```
request = requestAnimationFrame(this.drawWind.bind(this));

  @Input() set speeddata(speed: number){
    this.windvalue = speed;
    this.stopAnimation(this.request);
    this.drawWind();
  }

  stopAnimation(req) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(req);
  }
```

with `cancelAnimationFrame()` hoping that it will get requestID to stop the ongoing animation but it didn't work.

Comment: *"I tried to do something with cancelAnimationFrame() but nothing worked'* Show us that, because it's how you would solve the problem. So we can help you figure out why it didn't if we see what you did.

Comment: The edit shows you writing to a freestanding variable (`request`) and then later trying to use another freestanding variable with a different name (`req`). At a minimum, the names must match, and if this is instance-specific you need to make it an instance property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `drawWind` sets up the next call every time it's called, it makes sense that when you call it from the click handler, now you have two series of it running in parallel and things go twice as fast.

You said you tried `cancelAnimationFrame` but didn't show us that code. That is indeed how you would deal with this:

```
drawWind() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(this.rafHandle);
  this.rafHandle = requestAnimationFrame(this.drawWind.bind(this));
```

Now, when the button click calls `drawWind` while it has an `rAF` callback scheduled, it cancels that callback and sets a new one. So you still only have the one series running.

Comment: Just got 1 more question. Why doesn't the animation stopes? If we are setting `rafHandle` to `requestAnimationFrame(this.drawWind.bind(this))` and the function repeats shouldn't `cancelAnimationFrame` stope it since it receives the previous callback number?

Comment: @IoannisMikhaylidis - Because the next thing we do is schedule a new callback (which will schedule another one when called, which...).